I'm getting a 404 error from codepen when I execute my javascript code
Why does codepen thrown an error when I try to run this javascript?
It doesn't throw there error unless I get into the last else statement.
https://codepen.io/bnjwin/pen/YzbQOzo
    else {
    let result ="";
    for (const [symbol, number] of numerals) {
      while (input >= number) {
        result += symbol;
        input -= number;
      }
    }
    output.innerText = result;
  }

I built this code on freecodecamp.org and it works there.
I was expecting it to work on codepen.

The difference is clicking the button (doesn't 404) and pressing enter to submit the form (does 404).   Add e.preventDefault(); to the keydown event.

The codepen works for me.

@fdomn-m Any idea why? The code for enter just does convertBtn.click(), which should be the same as clicking on the button.

@Barmar If a form only has one input, then pressing enter will submit that form.  Temporarily remove the keydown event to remove the confusion.  More info on this question

The 404 error is coming from this: <script src="script.js"> it has nothing to do with the form submission.

@Barmar open pen, type a number, press enter -> 404.   Unless that's a coincidence and there's some other issue.

Does this answer your question? Why does forms with single input field submit upon pressing enter key in input

Use event.preventDefault() in the keydown handler when you're translating Enter to click.

thank you for the feedback. Adding the event.preventDefault() seemed to do the trick!
